# No named parameter with the name 'itemCount'. in Flutter GridView

Tags: gridview, flutter

I have error says :

> "No named parameter with the name 'itemCount'. in Flutter GridView "

Can Anyone help for solve this error. I am beginner in flutter.

My code as below.

```
class Items extends StatelessWidget {
  List list;
  Items({this.list});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemCount:list==null?0:list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,i){
          return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                 new Text(list[i]['name']),
                 new Text(list[i]['slug'])
                ],
              ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `GridView` class [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.html) there's no parameter called `itemCount`. The `GridView` constructor only receives the widget `list` to deduce the number of items. If you want another variation of the `GridView` class constructor where you can explicitly specify the `itemCount` you can use `GridView.builder` constructor.